# Android dynamic String Resources

Tags: android, android-resources

in my app I do a web request that returns some result code, e.g. 105. I have string resources that look like that

```
<string name="r105">O.K.</string>
<string name="r106">Something went wrong.</string>
<string name="r333">Fatal error.</string>
```

Now I want to do something like that

```
Toast.makeText(parent.getApplicationContext(),
        parent.getString(R.string.r+resultCode), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

while `r+resultCode` is the resource identifier.

This does not work. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: In above code you used resource as r105 but, while accessing you written R.string.r Is it correct ??

Comment: Now I understood your question, i will try give me 5 min.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this `getResources().getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage)` in a simple way.

```
Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getIdentifier("r"+resultcode, "string", 
getPackageName()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using `getResources().getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage)`. Something like this:

```
// Assuming resultCode is an int, use %s for String
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(String.format("r%d", resultCode), 
                                      "string", getPackageName());
String result = getString(id);
```

Comment: Ah, I thought resultCode was an int. Try %s for string or just do "r"+resultCode.

Answer (score -1):

Try as below, its working for me. Use `parent.getApplicationContext()` for you.

```
String str = getString(R.string.r)+resultCode;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: I think getString(R.string.r)+resultCode wont work because there is no resource called "r"

Comment: I given part of my code only, not entire thing. I used it in my project in xml file.

Comment: I have updated my question, no it is not working because R.string.r fails, there is no resource r