# Is it possible to load resources using Strings in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android dynamic String Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668093/android-dynamic-string-resources)

I have the following:

```
TextView text = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
TextView txtSub = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtSub);
TextView txtA = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtA);
TextView txtB = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtB);
```

Is it possible to access these using a String instead (this just pseudocode)?

```
String resourceName = "text";
TextView text = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id. + resourceName);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Resources.getIdentifier()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
int resource = getResources().getIdentifier("R.id."+resourceName, "string", getPackageName());
TextView text = (TextView)vi.findViewById(resource);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post : [Find view by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831506/find-view-by-name)

You need to get an id from your identifier. Once you have your id, use findById normally.